# Can't run Minecraft 1.8 or later

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I know that when 1.8 came out originally, I could run it just fine, though not anymore.  I normally play 1.7.10 because that's the latest version that some of my mods are available in, but today I tried to load up 1.8.7 without mods.  Turns out Minecraft can't run anything past 1.7.10- 1.8 and later all result in this:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fedf30c475, pid=2800, tid=7648

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build
1.8.0_25-b18)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)  Problematic frame:  C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x30c475]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I've tried re-downloading Minecraft and using different versions of Java, but nothing works and I still can't load anything past 1.7.10.

EDIT: I tried the older Minecraft.exe launcher.  Seems to work fine with that one, but not the other two.  huh

Comment: Have you tried completely uninstalling all versions of java, then reinstalling the latest version. Some quick research pointed to java being corrupted as a likely cause.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to reinstall ig4icd64.dll**

```
Problematic frame: C [ig4icd64.dll+0x30c475]
```

You can download it here : https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/ig4icd64_dll.html

Once that is downloaded place it in C:\Windows\System32\

**Be careful however as that contains very important system files.**

If that fails, it's a problem with your graphics card or your CPU's integrated graphics, as that file is responsible for OpenGL.

Comment: Rather than downloading a random dll, I suggest actually reinstalling the intel graphics drivers.